# Use python regex to extract sentences matching in a list of words

Tags: python, regex

I have a PDF which I have converted to string using the tika library. I wish to extract the first sentence only, where any of the keywords from the list below match. So far I have only been able to use regex to extract sentences with one keyword. I'm not sure how to iterate the list:
example:

`keywords = ['date','special function','strategy','biometric','system test']`

PDF output:

`'The date was October 19th.' Special function is this ', 'financial crisis in 2008.' we must have a strategy ', 'best strategy.' 'Biometric key prints are helpful.''Testing testing testing.'`

Desired Output

```
The date was October 19th. 
Special function is this.
we must have a strategy. 
Biometric key prints are helpful.
```

Thank you

Comment: Place your regex method `.search()` or `.findall()` inside a `for` loop

Comment: Is your pdf output a string or a list of string?

Comment: its a list of strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy to achieve what you want

```py
import re
# join the PDF lines into a multiline string
PDF = '\n'.join(['The date was October 19th.',
                 'Special function is this ', 
                 'financial crisis in 2008.',
                 'we must have a strategy ', 
                 'best strategy.', 
                 'Biometric key prints are helpful.', 
                 'Testing testing testing.'])

# the keywords
keywords = ['date','special function','strategy','biometric','system test']

# generate the pattern
pattern = r'.*\b(?='+'|'.join(keywords) + r')\b.*'
# resulting pattern .*\b(?=date|special function|strategy|biometric|system test)\b.*


print('\n'.join(re.findall(pattern, PDF, re.IGNORECASE)))
```

The pattern `.*\b(?=keyword1|keyword2|keyword3)\b.*` means to match any line that contains any one of the keywords ie `[keyword1, keyword2, keyword3]`.
[you can find the code snippet here](https://repl.it/repls/StormyInfamousInstructions)

Comment: thank you! I get the error `expected string or bytes-like object` for the last line, any idea why?

Comment: I forgot to pass the PDF string. @q21311 try it now

Comment: thanks - how can I match only the first occurance of the keyword? currently all sentences are showing with a match

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
keywords=list()
file=open('pdf file')
#spliting the pdf file to search through it
for line in file:
    spliting_words=line.split()
    #Making a while loop to find the word and put them into a list
    while True:
        if regx=re.findall('^The /s+.',line):
            keywords.append(line)
        elif regx=re.findall('^Special /s+ this.',line):
            keywords.append(line)
        elif keywords=re.findall('^we /s+ .',line):
            keywords.append(line)
        elif regx=re.findall('^Biometric /s+ .',line):
            keywords.append(line)
        else:
            break
#The word that you want
print(keywords)
```

Comment: Please post you answer and not an image url